# Pagination with dots (on Lollipop) : ViewPagerIndicator vs PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, viewpagerindicator, pagerslidingtabstrip

There are a lot of sources and samples for both. I need a pager with dots as indicator and I m working with the new Studio on Android 5.0.

From a first look;

- `PagerSlidingTabStrip` looks newer and i managed to import it as a
  gradle project and test.
- `ViewPagerIndicator` sample app on appstore might be removed. All
  links in the posts seem to be broken. And I couldnT import as a
  Gradle project either.

I was inclined to use the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` but I am not sure if the pagination with small dots is easily configurable with the 'PagerSlidingTabStrip', as far as I understood, it s mostly designed for tabs with titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is super simple to solve on your own here is a sample.

Add a LinearLayout(@+id/indContainer) below your ViewPager and then use this code to set the dots:

```
LinearLayout indContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indicator_container);
    for(int x=0;x<yourData.size();x++){
        ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
        int px = (int)(4 * (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 160));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(px,0,px,0);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.indicator_inactive);
        indContainer.addView(v);
    }
```

then in your pageChangeListener:

```
LinearLayout indContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indicator_container);
((ImageView) indContainer.getChildAt(position)).setImageResource(R.drawable.indicator_active);
((ImageView) indContainer.getChildAt(lastPage)).setImageResource(R.drawable.indicator_inactive);
lastPage = position;
```

Adjust as necessary for indicator icons and sizes

Comment: Hi, is this using `ViewPagerIndicator` or `PagerSlidingTabStrip`?

Comment: neither, this is just using a custom view

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.